# ajax call to cross domain using jsonp

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

Hello I am struggling to get this work.

```
var url = 'http://xxxx/getCustomerCardInfo?requestor_email=honey@gmail.com&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

The ajax call is successful. But this url gives the JSON in response i.e

```
{"targetRequestUri":"/getCustomerCardInfo","javax.servlet.request.key_size":256,"outputMap":{"emailId":"honey@gmail.com","orderList":[{"orderId":"ST210340","orderDate":"2013-04-24 07:12:54.187","orderStatus":"ORDER_COMPLETED","totalMoney":1}],"partyId":"10810","customerName":"honey goyal","telephoneNumber ":"9023605155"},"_FORWARDED_FROM_SERVLET_":true,"javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite":"DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA","thisRequestUri":"json"}
```

But my Firefox error console gives the error in JSON:-

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

on second character of beginning of JSON,  i mean on " in

```
{"targetRequestUr
```

And I does not get any alert. Any idea what i was doing wrong.
I think this need only JSONP response and padding is missing in above JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. I need to append padding before the JSON from web Server.
But this is not perfect solution according to me because it force me to change third party code. Still waiting for the perfect one so it can work by only changes to client side scripting. like

```
functionName({"firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith","age": 25});
```